# Autoloading data when scrolling with jqGrid in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

My problem is that while trying to implement usage of the Autoload feature, I cannot get it to make GET requests to my Action at all to attempt to load the next set of data. **The first initial load works fine**

I tried following the example here http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

The feature is listed under the item on the left hand side titled New in Version 3.4 - Autoloading when scrolling

What is the mistake here?

Here is my js grid code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#gvEmps').jqGrid(
   {
      url:'RecordEmpGrid',
      datatype: 'json',
      colNames:['Select Training(s)'],
      colModel :
      [
         {name: 'Select Training(s)', index: 'TrainingName', width: '300', align: 'Left'}
      ],
   rowNum: 15,
   scroll: true,
   rowList:[10,20,30],
   pager: '#gvEmpsPager',
   sortname: 'TrainingName',
   viewrecords: true,
   sortorder: 'desc',
   jsonReader:
   {
      repeatitems : true,
   },
   caption: ''
});
});
</script>
```

Html

```
<table id="gvEmps" class="SGrid scroll"></table>
<div id="gvEmpsPager" class="scroll"></div>
```

Controller

```
    //will never hit this action when scrolling, only first time on page load
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RecordEmpGrid(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var gr = new GridResult(sidx, sord, page, rows);
        var skip = rows * page - rows;
        DataTable dt = null;
        using (var mr = new MultipleRecords(Product.Utility, "evaluateSql"))
        {
            mr["sql"] = "SELECT * FROM TT.Training WHERE CompanyId = 190 ORDER BY TrainingName ASC";
            dt = mr.GetDataTable();
        }
        gr.Total = dt.Rows.Count;
        var records = new MultipleRecords(dt);
        foreach (var row in records.Skip(skip).Take(rows))
        {
            gr.AddDataRow(new []{row["TrainingTypeID"].String, row["TrainingName"].String });
        }
        return Json(gr.Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My json wrapper object

```
public class GridResult
{
    private List<object> m_rowData = new List<object>();

    private string m_order;
    private string m_idx;
    private int m_rows;
    private int m_page;

    public int Total { get; set; }

    public GridResult()
    {

    }

    public GridResult(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        m_idx = sidx;
        m_order = sord;
        m_page = page;
        m_rows = rows;
    }

    public void AddDataRow(object[] columnData)
    {
        m_rowData.Add(columnData);
    }

    private object m_data;
    public object Data
    {
        get
        {
            return m_data ?? (m_data = BuildData());
        }
    }

    protected object BuildData()
    {
        var id = 1;
        return new
        {
            total = Total,
            page = m_page++,
            records = m_rows,
            rows = (from row in m_rowData
                    select new
                    {
                        id = id++,
                        cell = row
                    }
                    ).ToArray()
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was inside my json helper object. I blame poor naming conventions for this but it appears that I was mixing the records & total parameters up.

```
total = //Number of records of the page
records = //Total number of records that can be loaded


protected object BuildData()
{
    var id = 1;
    return new
    {
        total = _rows, // <-- Number of rows total for a page limit (15 in my case)
        page = m_page++,
        records = Total, //<-- Total number of records possible to load (121 in my case)
        rows = (from row in m_rowData
                select new
                {
                    id = id++,
                    cell = row
                }
                ).ToArray()
    };
}
```

switching those two solved the problem.

Here is a great link that lead me to the discovery. This guy is a jqGrid guru.

http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/15/38212/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full working example I wrote for you in which I have hardcoded the values but you could adapt it easily to fit your needs.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult RecordEmpGrid(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var gr = new GridResult(sidx, sord, page, rows);
        var skip = rows * page - rows;
        gr.Total = 75;
        foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, gr.Total).Skip((page - 1) * rows).Take(rows))
        {
            gr.AddDataRow(new[] { string.Format("TrainingName: {0}", item) });
        }
        return Json(gr.Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#gvEmps').jqGrid({
                url: '@Url.Action("RecordEmpGrid")',
                datatype: 'json',
                colNames: ['Select Training(s)'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Select Training(s)', index: 'TrainingName', width: '300', align: 'Left' }
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                scroll: true,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#gvEmpsPager',
                sortname: 'TrainingName',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: true
                },
                caption: '',
                height: 100
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="gvEmps"></table>
    <div id="gvEmpsPager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the controller name in the ajax call (url:'/controllername/actionname')
I hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry that i forgot to mention but I am just using some custom routing that allows me to leave of the controller name in this particular case. Keep in mind, it loads the first set of records fine, its just the auto loading during scrolling that totally fails.

Comment: Do you have the view name as RecordEmpGrid?

Comment: No, the name of the view is Record.cshtml

Comment: I don't see how that will help simply because it is not even being invoked ... can't really help to change what it returns if it never gets there

Comment: According to the jqGrid documentation, you must return page, total and records params. It seems that you are only returning data

Comment: My apologies again. I didn't think it necessary to post my helper object that is turning all the data into json. I posted it up so you can take a look, as you will notice, it is not neglected any of the record parameters that you listed. **scratches head*** I even did a little more implementation on the Action and still no dice!