# True scrolling data in JQGrid not working with MVC 3

Tags: jqgrid

Can someone help me with this issue?
I have a jqgrid(4.4.0) and I want to implement true scrolling. The problem is that it only loads datarows once, meaning the first page only. So when I scroll, it doesn't fetch the other pages. I have checked [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290242/autoloading-data-when-scrolling-with-jqgrid-in-mvc) and still not working.

Here is the jqgrid:

```
jQuery("#deptProjectsGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUserProjects", "TimesheetByWeek")',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Projekt', 'Oprettet af'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'project', index: 'project', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'creator', index: 'creator', align: 'left' }
                  ],
        height: 300,
        width: 250,
        altRows: true,
        pager: '#pager1',
        scroll: 1,
        rowNum: 15,
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortname: 'project',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        gridview: true,
        caption: "Projekter",
        onSelectRow: function (ids) {
            if (ids == null) {
                ids = 0;
                if ($taskgrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') > 0) {
                    $taskgrid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: '@Url.Action("GetProjectTasks", "TimesheetByWeek")/' + ids });
                    $taskgrid.jqGrid('setCaption', "No Tasks " + ids).trigger('reloadGrid');
                }
            } else {
                var data = $("#deptProjectsGrid").getRowData(ids);
                $taskgrid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: '@Url.Action("GetProjectTasks", "TimesheetByWeek")/' + ids });
                $taskgrid.jqGrid('setCaption', "Tasks for " + data.project).trigger('reloadGrid');
            }
        }
    });
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
public JsonResult GetUserProjects(int page, int rows, string search, string sidx, string sord)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DanishEntities db = new DanishEntities()) 
            {

                int totalRecords = 0;
                var allProjectEntities = _projectRepository.GetProjectsPaged(page, rows, out totalRecords, db);
                var projects = Mapper.Map<List<Project>, List<ProjectModel>>(allProjectEntities);

                var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecords / (float)rows);
                var jsonData = new
                {
                    total = rows,
                    page = page++,
                    records = totalRecords,
                    rows = (
                               from p in projects
                               select new
                               {
                                   id = p.ID,
                                   cell = new object[] { p.Name, "john doe" }
                               }).ToArray()
                };
                return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

and the query is:

```
public List<Project> GetProjectsPaged(int page, int rows, out int totalCount, DanishEntities dbContext)
    {
        List<Project> pagedProjectEntities = new List<Project>();
        try
        {

            totalCount = dbContext.Projects.Count();
            pagedProjectEntities = dbContext.Projects
                    .OrderBy(p => p.ID)
                    .Skip((page-1) * rows)
                    .Take(rows)
                    .ToList();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return pagedProjectEntities;
    }
```

I have wasted 4 hours of my life trying to figure this out and I just can't see the problem. I have even set "total = totalPages" in the controller action but nothing is working. Help please!!
Just another quick question on jqGrid: How do I disable "rowNum" in a jqGrid so that the grid shows all available rows returned by the query in the data set?

Comment: Maybe this is not the problem but in you `jsonData` change `total = rows` to `total = totalPages`

Comment: @nemesv Thanks for the reply, but I have tried that already and it did not work. I forgot to mention that I am using jqGrid 4.4.0. Maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: @MattBodily Unfortunately I don't have enough hours left to start over with a new grid component. That would be for the next version maybe.